# Does Phantasm Stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

The rune for Spirit Barrage, Phantasm, deals damage over time in a small area of effect. If I overlap them and an enemy is standing on 2 or more at once, does it take double, triple, etc. damage? Or can an enemy only be affected by a single Phantasm at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do stack in damage.

But, you can only have three Phantasms at one time.
If you cast a fourth, the first one disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this pre-1.0.4 (since my main was a WD), and it stacks, adding another Phantasm on the area. Most likely it still works.